# Is "we introduce few notation" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

In my research article, I wrote:

> We now introduce few notations.

Then the referees for the paper told me that using 'notations' is grammatically incorrect. So I'm thinking about changing it to

> We now introduce few notation.

To me this sounds a bit strange now without the 's' from the notations. I was wondering is this grammatically correct? Thank you.

Comment: It definitely sounds weird to me. I guess it is ungrammatical as well. Your second sentence I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is non-idiomatic, but not grammatically incorrect. It's the opposite of "We now introduce many notations." and emphasizes that there's only a small number of them. That's probably not what you want; you want to say that there is more than one, so in that case you need 'a few' ('some' would work too).

> We now introduce *a* few notations.

See e.g. page 2 of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885064X08000034/pdf?md5=6d950c9be6f4f7d9ac04dcf21c175b5e&pid=1-s2.0-S0885064X08000034-main.pdf) where a similar construction is used.

'Few' is always followed by a plural, so the second sentence is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Depending on the field and subject matter, "we now introduce **some** new notation" might be more idiomatic. (Specifically, mathematical notation might be introduced this way.)